# UIImageView crashes due to memory warning, trying to load a huge array of images

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uislider

I am making an application just like a movie player but instead of showing a video, I have the movie in image frames. A slider is used to move the "movie" forward and backward and if released, the "movie" is auto played up to a chapter.
I accomplish this by having a `UIImageView` and changing the `image` property on each value change of the slider. After a while the app crashes due to memory warning. I cannot use the animation of UIImage because I want to control the position (aka visible image/frame) by scrubbing the slider. 
So I have an ImageManager class that loads all the image names in string in an array (total 1500 images of about 150kb each) on init.

```
- (id) initWithCanvas:(UIImageView*) canvasView{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        totalImages = 1500;
        self.canvas = canvasView;
        self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<totalImages; i++){
            [self.images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame_%04d.jpg", i]]; 
            i = i + 4; // I use this to skip 4 frames
        }
        previewsImageIndex = -1;
        [self setImageAtPosition:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I have a function that is fired on value change of the UISlider which finds the current image name and constructs a UIImage from the image name and sets it to the UIImageView

```
- (void) setImageAtPosition:(CGFloat)percentage{
    currentImage = nil;
    int position = percentage * [self.images count];
    if (position != previewsImageIndex){
        previewsImageIndex = position;
        NSLog(@"Got image:%d at percentage: %f", position, percentage);
        if (position < [self.images count]){
            self.canvas.image = nil;
            currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.images objectAtIndex:position]];
            [self.canvas setImage:currentImage];
            currentImage = nil;
            //[currentImage release];
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I set the currentImage and the canvas.image as nil, still after a while the app crashes. I don't understand where am I having a memory leak. Also, I code with ARC, so no releasing.

Is there any other better way to do it, other than having a UIImage view? I want frame-by-frame view ability and the MPMoviePlayer or AVPlayer cannot do that fine-grained scrubbing.

Comment: Do not use `imageNamed` because it will cache your images.

Comment: Please show the declaration for `currentImage`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams UIImage* currentImage; But it was the `imageNamed` that did the bad stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@""]` method, as that doesn't cache images. `imageNamed:` caches any images that are loaded through it.

Comment: it worked! Although I had to get the full path with `NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.images objectAtIndex:position] ofType:@"jpg"];`. Guess I should read the documentation more often since it is described there about the caching